# Proper wiring for dishwasher and GFCI

Tags: wiring, code-compliance, dishwasher

Can I connect a dishwasher to a GFCI outlet that is part of a 20amp circuit that has a total of 2 GFCI outlets?

Comment: Where are the existing GFCI outlets?

Answer (score 2):

In almost every scenario the answer would be no. If the receptacles you are talking about are general use or serving the counter areas in the kitchen then the answer is definitely no.